# get value from file configuration ini

Tags: php, config

I have two file: file of configuration config.ini which contains value of database configuration, and file index.php

how include the file config.ini in index.php and how to get specific value from the config.ini

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use http://php.net/manual/de/function.parse-ini-file.php to read the .ini file and get the content as an associative array.